# Best way to store static data to be bundled with application?

Tags: java, database, data-structures

I'm writing an application in java that will facilitate creating wireless sensor networks using off the shelf micro controllers, sensors, and radios. Each sensor and radio will most likely require unique code. I'm planning on creating skeletons for each platform and and then having modular bits of code for each sensor and radio that can be plugged into these skeletons. This will result in a library of static information that will be used to dynamically generate code for these sensors.

I'm not sure what the best way to store and organize this data would be. I started off trying to create classes for each sensor encapsulating its unique properties but using objects for data storage only seems weird. I feel like SQL would be overkill as the data isn't really changing and I would also like to keep everything in version control. Should I just use flat files? XML? Any advice on how to architect this project would be very welcome.

Comment: That's a pretty big question. *"skeletons for each platform"* - what platforms? Wouldn't the platform be the OS that can run java and provide IO to the micro-controllers? Java is meant to be platform independent.
*"...will most likely require unique code"*. If you're not sure on that, I wouldn't start abstracting just yet. Finish one implementation, then do another, and re-use what is common. The perfect design will emerge.

Comment: Allow me to clarify, the purpose of the java application is to generate source for OTHER platforms (Arduino, etc). This will be done by way of assembling pre-written snippets of source (not java) into something that can be flashed onto one of these micro controllers. So the question is where should I put and how should I organize all these snippets i'm going to write?

Comment: That's really hard to answer without knowing more about what input you expect, what the data looks like, how the output is generated (perhaps a templating system, or XSLT), how much is common about these devices, etc.. My advice is the same: prototype it for one system (one instance of each device class), *use* it (define an API), and re-iterate (add more implementations). How the data is stored, and how you should organize your classes will show itself if you try to write as little code as possible (re-use as much as you can). Keep it simple, and only introduce complexity when needed.

Comment: The functionality of each generated piece of code is basically limited to: read data->vomit onto mesh network. The only variation is the sensor being read and the connection being used, these are the 'Inputs' the user gives. Its possible that there might be some commonality between some platforms but at the moment i'm assuming they're all unique.

Comment: My first reaction was to create say an "ArduinoPhotosensor" class that could answer to something like "ArduinoPhotosensor.getSensorDataFunction" by returning a string of arduino code, but this seems messy and unscalable. I'm not really familiar with some of the things you mentioned (XSLT, templating, etc), maybe these are the answers, would you mind giving some more general advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating source, I'd go binary. Conceptually, that is.

Why would the source code need to change if a device is plugged in or out? Simply compile binary device driver libraries and link them to the main app.
There is an assembler, so likely there is a linker.

If there is no linker, and you are forced to use a monolithic source file, then at least we can use the *concepts* of a linker.

**Linking Source Code**

For inspiration and details I'd look into *Operating System Design* a little bit, for the concepts of *device drivers*,  and *IO devices*, and *network sockets*. I'd use this to take a hard look at the source that would be generated, and what exactly changes if a device is changed, and fix it so that as little as possible, ideally nothing, has to be changed.

The code for the app running on the (presumably embedded) system should be maintained separate from the device drivers, so here is where the abstraction needs to begin. It needs to be refactored to abstract away the particulars of the devices into *abstract device classes*.

So this is the first step: refactor the generated source to abstract out the particulars of the device drivers so that you have a main 
application that calls *functions* via *symbols*.

This allows the main app to work regardless of the number and kind of devices available.

Next, I'd look into *compiler theory*, particularly the concepts of *symbol resolution* and *static/dynamic linking*, and *stub*. Since the generated source is refactored so that there is a main application and a list of device drivers, all that is left is to make the devices available to the application.

**Illustration**

The application could generate the source code to be assembled by concatenating the source for the main application with the source for the device drivers.

It would provide a *stub* as well: a small library providing a function to iterate the devices and interrogate their classes.

Your application then becomes so simple that a one-liner on a *NIX prompt could do it. No Java required:

```
cat program stub drivers/foo drivers/bar > generated-source-or-binary
```

In it's simplest form, the `program` would contain a call to an `iterate_devices` label in `stub`.

Here's a layout of the source and/or binary image:

```
// application
main() {
   for ( device in list_devices() ) {
      switch ( device.class ) {
         ....
      }
   }
}

// stub
list_devices() {
   for ( device = first; device != null; device += *cur )
      yield device;       
}
first: // drivers follow

// drivers/foo
dev_foo: .long dev_foo_end - . // size
....
dev_foo_end

// drivers/bar
dev_bar: .long dev_bar_end - .
....
dev_bar_end
```

**Organizing Driver Sources**

This shouldn't have to be more complicated than a directory with files.

A simple approach would be to include these in the .jar in a specific package. For instance, having a class provide driver sources like this:

```
package myapp.drivers;
public class DriverSource {
    public static InputStream getDriverSource( String identifier ) {
        return this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
           this.getClass().getPackage().getName().replace('.', '/')
           + '/' + identifier + '.source'
        );
    }
}
```

would require the driver sources to be put in `myapp/drivers/{identifier}.source`. In a standard eclipse project, you'd place the files in `src/myapp/drivers/`. Using Maven, you'd put them in `src/main/resources/myapp/drivers/`. You can also put them in another directory, as long as they are copied as resources to the proper package directory.

The above class could also serve as a basis for more complex storage: you could query a remote service and download the source files, or query an SQL database. But resource files will be a decent start.

Comment: I think we're more on the same page then you realize. the skeletons I mentioned are exactly what you described, code with the 'driver' functionality abstracted out and you're right, that doesn't change. In essence what i'm building in java IS a linker, though its operating on the actual source and not the binary level as you recommend because a) I've never done anything like that and b) i'm not sure its possible (granted java probably isn't the best but its what i'm comfortable with). The actual question which you didn't go over was how should i store and organize these 'drivers'?

Comment: Good to know! Operating on the source like that is fine of course. Being able to (mostly) concatenate source files greatly simplifies things. I updated the answer to more explicitly cover your question. However, without knowing more about the number of drivers, and their commonality (maybe they all include the same header file?), I can't get more specific.

Comment: The entire project once completed will probably include somewhere around a hundred drivers. In addition to the code inside the driver I also need to keep track of its hardware reqs (number of I/O pins? Analog? Digital?, etc) and any required libraries. I'm looking at xml to organize this data. I could use attributes for things like required libraries, pins, and ofcourse the code to by substituted into the main program. Does this seem like a sane way to do it? I could even put all the sensor drivers for a given platform into a single file to keep it cleaner.

Comment: What format is most suited mostly depends on how you *use* the information. An XML file is extensible and will definitely hold all the information, including the source, but is relatively cumbersome. You could also add a little header to the source file (in a comment section) with the hardware reqs, required libraries etc, and parse that, or store that in a separate .properties file. Is the data going to be read-only by your application, or will there be a management interface to add/update devices? In that case an embedded DB might be better suited.